# MySQL group_concat() function with join operation

Tags: mysql

I have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE school(
    schoolId VARCHAR(36),
    sname VARCHAR(64)
    PRIMARY KEY(schoolId)
);

CREATE TABLE school_building(
    schoolId VARCHAR(36),
    bname VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY(schoolId, bname),
    FOREIGN KEY (schoolId) REFERENCES school(schoolId)
);

CREATE TABLE school_faculty(
    schoolId VARCHAR(36),
    fname VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY(schoolId, fname),
    FOREIGN KEY (schoolId) REFERENCES school(schoolId)
);
```

I want to write a query to retrieve schools along with their buildings and faculties as comma separated fields. When i write only the following:

```
SELECT school.*, group_concat(bname SEPARATOR ',') as buildings, group_concat(fname SEPARATOR ',') as faculties 
FROM school S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_building B 
on S.schoolId = B.schoolId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_faculty F 
on S.schoolId = F.schoolId 
GROUP BY school.schoolId;
```

it gives the result exactly as I want. However, I want to write a query to select schools along with their buildings and school faculties as comma separated fields if building name or faculty name meets some conditions. For example, i want to select schools if (it has Medicine or Engineering faculty) or (it has Hospital or Restaurant) building. For this, i write the following:

```
SELECT school.*, group_concat(bname SEPARATOR ',') as buildings, group_concat(fname SEPARATOR ',') as faculties 
FROM school S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_building B 
on S.schoolId = B.schoolId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_faculty F 
on S.schoolId = F.schoolId 
WHERE B.name in ('hospital', 'restaurant') or F.name in ('medicine', 'engineering') 
GROUP BY school.schoolId;
```

However, although this query returns correct schools, it brings buildings or faculties incorrectly. For example, assume a school has three buildings with names hospital and hotel. However, in the result set, school only has hospital. Apparently, where clause somehow prevents buildings whose theirs are not listed in where clause from being comma separated by group_concat(). How can I fix this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, you want to bring back all the buildings and faculties for a school when they have one of the required ones.

There are possibly a couple of ways to do this. You could use a couple of sub queries to find schools that have the requisite building or faculties, and then join that back against the main query.

Or another way would be to use FIND_IN_SET using HAVING to check that the fields contain the building or faculty as required.

```
SELECT school.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bname SEPARATOR ',') AS buildings, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fname SEPARATOR ',') AS faculties 
FROM school S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_building B 
ON S.schoolId = B.schoolId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_faculty F 
ON S.schoolId = F.schoolId 
GROUP BY school.schoolId 
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('hospital', buildings)
OR FIND_IN_SET('restaurant', buildings)
OR FIND_IN_SET('engineering', faculties) 
OR FIND_IN_SET('medicine', faculties)
```

EDIT

Using piotrms suggestion:-

```
SELECT S.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.bname SEPARATOR ',') AS buildings, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT F.fname SEPARATOR ',') AS faculties 
FROM school S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_building B1 
ON S.schoolId = B1.schoolId 
AND B1.bname IN ('hospital', 'restaurant')
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_building B 
ON S.schoolId = B.schoolId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_faculty F1 
ON S.schoolId = F1.schoolId 
AND F1.fname IN ('engineering', 'medicine')
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_faculty F 
ON S.schoolId = F.schoolId 
WHERE B1.schoolId IS NOT NULL OR F1.schoolId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY S.schoolId ;
```

Comment: This would work after fixing some syntax, but it would be better to just add inner joins of buildings and facilities with desired attributes in on condition. Not only faster as optimizer would restrict rows to those with proper attributes first but also you avoid problems with commas in the names.

Comment: But you would lose the other buildings and faculties (and they would need to still be LEFT OUTER JOINs as the requirement is if there is a match on building or faculty, not necessarily both). If these are not required (not clear from the original question, but it does seem they probably want the other ones) then the query can be far simpler.

Comment: I meant adding additional 2 joins, not replacing current left joins.

Comment: They would still need to be left outer joins (as it could be a matching building OR faculty, so legitimate for one of the joins to not match), but that would match up with putting the checks in the ON conditions (which is pointless with an inner join).

Comment: You need inner joins to restrict results to matching schools fast, doing a group_concat on a huge set of all possible schools just to see which have desired buildings or facilities is what I want to avoid. I'll just post my answer.

Comment: You cannot use INNER JOINs though, as that would exclude a school that had a matching building name but no matching faculty name, hence my sql above that is using your suggestion but using LEFT OUTER JOINs and then checking for a not null row in one of them in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT S.*, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.bname SEPARATOR ',') AS buildings, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT F.fname SEPARATOR ',') AS faculties 
FROM school S INNER JOIN school_building B1 INNER JOIN school_faculty F1
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_building B ON S.schoolId = B.schoolId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN school_faculty F ON S.schoolId = F.schoolId
WHERE B1.schoolId = S.schoolId AND B1.bname IN ('hospital','restaurant')
   OR F1.schoolID = S.schoolId AND F1.fname IN ('medicine','engineering')
GROUP BY S.schoolId
```

See an example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01e67/1).

Comment: The inner joins there are in effect cross joins (with no ON clause). With the rows returned the WHERE clause processes the results, in effect emulating LEFT OUTER JOINs.

Comment: Looking at the execution plans they are different, the query with all left joins might be the best out of 3, though this needs testing on a bigger data set.

Comment: Fully agree, and with the data close to what will be used when live as that would make a major difference. I did explains of all 3 solutions and the one for your solution was quite unusual, far more different than I thought it would be (I expected it to be much the same as mine once MySQL got its head around it)